# Wamp server Put Online issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I have some problems with my wamp server put online feature. Recently I just tried to put my localhost to my local Wi-Fi network. It worked but with some issues. My local IP in the my network was 192.168.1.2. When I browse the IP from an another PC, it load HTML only. All other CSS, JS etc will not load. When I viewed the page source, it showing that the base path is http:// localhost/path-to-folder.  That means it is refers to the localhost of that system, not my localhost. How to solve this problem?

Sorry, a little more thing. I am using wordpres for my blog.

Comment: You have to code your scripts to use relative links or create something that detects URL and uses that. Instead of hardcoding localhost

Answer (score 1):

use relative paths in the code, right now you have used absolute path, with default domain as `http://localhost` refer to this doc http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Sorry. A little more thing. I was using wordpress. So, I don't know how to edit thins to change relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just change URL's to `192.168.1.2` instead of `localhost` in your code.